# Recognizing Permutation of Group with different Label

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

**Problem description:**
Assume, a group, $G \leq S_{26}$ , $S_{26}$ is a symmetric group.

Each permutation of $G$ is labeled using $1,2,....26$ as usual.
Suppose, $f$ is a function  that changes label of permutations.

Instead of $\{1,2,....26\}$, $f$ uses  $\{a,b,....z \} $ .
now, take   each element $\pi \in G$,  take  $f(\pi)$ and from set  $H$.

**Question:**

$G, H$ are given and $f$ is not.

For which group, we can find the bijection $f$ between $G$ and $H$?

A toy example:if $G$ has  permutation $(123)$ and $H$ has  permutation (d  e  f) we can say, $f(1)=d, f(2)=e, f(3)=f$.

Comment: if $G=S_n$  case is clear, so consider  $G < S_n$.

Comment: In your toy example there are three possibilities for $f$ not one. You could also have $f(1)=e$, $f(2)=f$, $f(3)=d$.

Comment: @DerekHolt yes  but the groups  might have  other elements to establish a canonical relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions are very difficult to understand. You have not really said what $H$ is for example. Is $H = \{ f(\pi) : \pi \in G \}$?

If I am understanding the question correctly, then $f$ is uniquely determined if and only if $C_{S_n}(G)=1$.

When $G$ is transitive, this is the case if and only if $G$ is nonabelian and primitive.